# How to identify button press among several button in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I have 4 button (b1,b2,b3,b4) and a label (lab).Now I want to display button title in label when a particular button is pressed.i did it with four (IBAction) method one for every button.But i want to do it with 1(IBAction) method.so the problem is to to how to identify which button is pressed??? i knew a method something like "getBytitle" method.But i need better solution.Can anyone help??? I also need answer about how to identify button in segment control.Advanced thanx for reply.

Comment: zoul,thax for your reply. But i used it before.Infact, i want to know is there any way to use Outlet to identify a particular button??is there any way to findout sender Outlet and then using sender currentTitle???

Comment: Objective c... for Mac App or iPhone App? they run a little bit diferently

Comment: thanx kevin.blair.Also thanx to balexandre.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look in IB, the tag field of the button attibutes might be what you are looking for. Set each of the buttons you want to detect with a different integer tag value, and then set their IBActions to the same method. Now you can check which button was pressed by checking for the tag field in the sender

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender
{
    switch ( ((UIButton*)sender).tag ){

       case 1:
               <something>
               break;
       case 2:
               <something else>
               break;

       default:
               <default something>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The button that triggers the action gets passed as the sender. Your method probably looks a bit like this:

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender;
```

The `sender` is the button, so that if you want to display the button title in a label, all you have to do is this:

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender
{
    label.text = [sender currentTitle];
}
```

That should be it.

Comment: this method should be added to my viewcontroller.m file correct? If I'm right, this is still not working for me.